# SQL - order by list order

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

I have the following query that returns rows based on a comma seperated list

```
Select * from Table where RecordID in (22,15,105,1,65,32)
```

I would like the results of this query to return to in the order of the ID's in the list. Is that possible with SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What SQL database system, or do you need something portable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need the output to appear in a particular order, then you need to specify that order, using something the server can sort. Not knowing which engine you're working against, the general scheme would be to create a temp table or use rowset constructors to pair each record ID with its desired sort order.

E.g. (SQL Server)

```
declare @T table (RecordID int,Position int)
insert into @T (RecordID,Position)
select 22,1 union all
select 15,2 union all
select 105,3 union all
select 1,4 union all
select 65,5 union all
select 32,6

select * from Table t inner join @T t2 on t.RecordID = t2.RecordID order by t2.Position
```

Answer (score 16):

```
select * from Table
where RecordID in (22,15,105,1,65,32)
order by (
    case RecordID 
        when 22 then 1
        when 15 then 2
        when 105 then 3
        when 1 then 4
        when 65 then 5
        when 32 then 6 end)
```

Comment: The recordId will be a dynamic list (forgot to mention that)

Comment: @twsJames - Since your statement looks like this `in (22,15,105,1,65,32)` you already are building your query dynamically so you might as well build the `order by` at the same time. If not, how do you parameterize your query with a dynamic list of values?

Answer (score 3):

I'd to the ordering in the client, but if you really want to do it in SQL, do it like this:

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1), RecordID int)

insert into @T (RecordID)
values (22), (15), (105), (1), (65), (32)

select * from 
[table] t 
inner join @t s on t.id=s.recordid
where t.id in (22, 15, 105, 1, 65, 32)
order by s.id
```

(works in SQL Server 2008)

Comment: I can't find any documentation either way on whether the order of rows within the table value constructor of an insert statement will be respected w.r.t. IDENTITY value assignments. That makes me nervous.

Comment: It is respected. Otherwise, you can always do it one by one.

Comment: You don't need `where t.id in (22, 15, 105, 1, 65, 32)` with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You add the `ORDER BY recordedid` clause at the end.

Comment: I don't think you get it: he wants the *same* order as in the query

Answer (score -1):

The last time I had to do this I ended up doing a union all and generating a select statement for each id, i.e.

```
select * from Table where RecordID = 22
union all
select * from table where recordid = 15
```

etc.

It was a pain but it worked.

Comment: There are no ordering guarantees from `UNION` or `UNION ALL` - the engine is free to return results in whatever order it finds most efficient. This may, by chance, return the results in the requested order, but anything (major version change, service pack, hotfix, workload on server, time of day, phase of the moon, colour of your shirt) could mean the results return in another order.

Comment: To do this you'd have to add a sequential value to each SELECT, e.g. SELECT [rank] = 1, * FROM Table WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT [rank] = 2, * FROM Table WHERE ...
ORDER BY [rank]. Of course this can become pretty expensive depending on what else might have to go in the WHERE clause, never mind if joins to other tables are required, so I certainly don't condone this approach. It is a pain for several reasons.

Answer (score -3):

Use `ORDER BY` against the `RecordID`

```
Select * from Table where RecordID in (22,15,105,1,65,32) ORDER BY RecordID
```

Comment: Hey Talha, i would like the records to be ordered in the same order as the list. e.g. Record 1 = id 22, Record 2 = id 15 etc. Is this possible