# Any standard SQL expression to sort results base on IN expression

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - order by list order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609184/sql-order-by-list-order)

Is there any standard SQL expression to sort results exactly base on IN expression. For example to return the results of the following query so that 2, 4, 6, 8 are returned serially?

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE ID IN (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: Well, for your case: ORDER BY ID ASC ;)  Just kidding, I don't know if there is something like this.

Comment: :). that's just an example. IDs are not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Give us exact code for an exact solution...

Comment: The exact code is the above. Just change IDs. A variable number of IDs are passed to a JSP in a comma-separated String. I want to know if this is possible to sort them according to the comma-separated list or not.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is doing a JOIN instead of an IN to a table with the original order with their ordinal rank

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE INNER JOIN SOMETABLE2 ...  etc
ORDER BY SOMETABLE2.original
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have full controlled over your SQL rendering, then use a CASE expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE ID 
-- render WHEN clauses in the desired order
WHEN 2 THEN 1 
WHEN 4 THEN 2
WHEN 6 THEN 3
WHEN 8 THEN 4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can pass the ids as a fixed delimited string, you can do the following :

```
-- Populate a number table
DECLARE @Temp Table(Number int)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(6)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(8)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(9)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES(10)

SELECT TOP 8000 Number = IDENTITY(int,1,1) INTO [dbo].Numberos FROM @TEMP t1, @TEMP t2, @TEMP t3, @TEMP t4

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Numbers] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Numbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Number])

-- This function splits a fixed delimited string into a table object
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fixstring_single](@str text, @itemlen tinyint) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN (SELECT listpos = n.Number, 
str = substring(@str, (@itemlen + 1) * (n.Number - 1) + 1, @itemlen) 
FROM Numbers n 
WHERE n.Number <= (datalength(@str)+1) / (@itemlen+1)) 

DECLARE @ids varchar(100);
SET @ids = '00002 00001 00004';

-- Join to the number table ordered by the posisiton in the ids string
SELECT * FROM TestT INNER JOIN fixstring_single(@ids, 5) S ON TestT.ID = S.Str ORDER BY S.listpos
```